# Why is the array sum coming less than the actual sum when OpenMP is used?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have written the following program in C using OpenMP library for parallel programming to find the sum of an array of size 10000000. The expected output should be sum of elements = 10000000 but the output I am getting is less than the sum.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARR_SIZE 10000000
int a[ARR_SIZE];
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
 int i,tid,numt;
int sum=0;
double t1,t2;
for(i=0;i<ARR_SIZE;i++)
a[i]=1;

t1=omp_get_wtime();

#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(i,tid)
{
int from,to;
tid=omp_get_thread_num();
numt=omp_get_num_threads();

from = (ARR_SIZE/numt)*tid;
to= (ARR_SIZE/numt)*(tid+1)-1;

if(tid == numt-1)
to= ARR_SIZE-1;

printf("Hello from %d of %d , my range is from = %d to %d \n",tid,numt,from,to);

for(i=from;i<=to;i++)
sum+=a[i];
}

t2=omp_get_wtime();

printf("Sum of the array elements = %d time = %g \n",sum,t2-t1);
return 0;
}
```

Some of the sample outputs are :

### Output 1

> Hello from 0 of 4 , my range is from = 0 to 2499999 
>   Hello from 3 of 4 , my range is from = 7500000 to 9999999 
>   Hello from 1 of 4 , my range is from = 2500000 to 4999999 
>   Hello from 2 of 4 , my range is from = 5000000 to 7499999 
>   Sum of the array elements = 3235618 time = 0.118754

### Output 2

> Hello from 3 of 4 , my range is from = 7500000 to 9999999 
>   Hello from 0 of 4 , my range is from = 0 to 2499999  
>   Hello from 2 of 4 , my range is from = 5000000 to 7499999  
>   Hello from 1 of 4 , my range is from = 2500000 to 4999999  
>   Sum of the array elements = 2964874 time = 0.129216

What is the reason that the given sum is less than the actual sum.

Comment: Point your favourite search engine at *OpenMP reduction*, or even search around on this site for the same topic.

Comment: And also look at "omp for". You are writing a pthread code that happens to start thread with OpenMP :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update of `sum` variable isn't an atomic operation and is prone to races. Races of this type are likely to yield a lesser than expected sum.

The summing boils down to something of this kind:

1. Load to register from memory location
2. Add new value to the register
3. Store the register value back to the memory

Now when 4 threads perform the above without consideration of one to another, some additions will be lost, resulting in a sum that is below of what was expected.

For example, with 2 threads (for simplicity):

```
Thread 1: Load to a register from memory location
Thread 2: Load to a register from memory location
Thread 1: Add new value to the register
Thread 2: Add new value to the register
Thread 1: Store the register value back to the memory
Thread 2: Store the register value back to the memory
```

In this example, at the end the addition of thread 1 will be overridden.

You should make sure the summation is done atomically to avoid races.

Comment: @codeczar I don't see how that could happen. The sum update in memory is the last operation in the sequence.

Comment: I had a slight confusion but it's resolved now and the problem is solved thanks for your answer